# Trouble importing and running the Google Cardboard sample project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cardboard

You can find the project here: https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard

The last time I worked with android was about a year ago and I'm trying to use this VR project to get back into it. All I want to do is mess around with the app to get a feel for it.

However, I haven't been able to get it running. I installed a fresh copy of Eclipse (juno) with the JDK and android SDK and got the android 4.4W stuff from the SDK manager. I also made a Nexus 5 AVD.

My problem is that I've tried choosing multiple 'root' folders to 'import as existing android project' and none of them have been runnable. Each time the eclipse terminal gives an 'Installation error: Unknown failure' error after installing 'MainActivity.apk'.

I figured the 'main' folder would be most likely to work since it has the manifest and all the other folders associated with android projects.

How do I get it running?

Comment: Have you tried using the feature in Eclipse that allows you to directly import a project from a git repository(Something like File->import->git->import from git)? Not sure if it will make a difference but it has solved some issues for me in the past that I ran into after I cloned the repository myself and tried to import it.

Comment: @jteezy14 I tried that just now and eclipse first told me that /users/.../git/cardboard wasn't empty so I emptied it. Now it tells me that there are no projects found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an Eclipse project. It is for use with Android Studio and Gradle. Your choices are:

- Switch to Android Studio, or
- See if somebody else has already reorganized that code into an Eclipse project, or
- Attempt to reorganize it yourself, moving the contents of `src/main/` into appropriate locations and fixing up the manifest for things that are set now in `build.gradle`, or
- Find something else as a project to get back into Android development

Answer (score 4):

[@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware): I have the project up and running on Eclipse(Juno) with Android 4.4.2

[@ThroatOfWinter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475521/throatofwinter57): These steps should help you. They worked for me.

- Download the project from github as a ZIP file
- Extract the contents of the ZIP file (named cardboard-master) into a folder and then import the whole folder into Eclipse as a new android project
- Create a new "libs" folder in your project
- To use the Cardboard API, download the [VR Toolkit .jar file](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard/blob/master/CardboardSample/libs/cardboard.jar) and include it in your project in the "libs" folder.

If everything has worked fine so far, you'll find that the "src" folder in your new Cardboard project is empty but the "java" folder contains 3 .java files.

- Create a new package in "src" called "com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt"
- Copy the 3 files from the "java" folder and paste in the package you created in the previous step.
- Clean and build the project
- Test on an android device (preferably) with the cardboard app installed

You shouldn't need to edit the manifest at all.

Comment: Its not working for me. In my case, it force close on runtime due to NoClassDeffException. If normal import without using gradle, we need to  add also google-guava to libs folder. Can get the jar from here : http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar

Comment: The solution from moyheen worked for me partially. I got some CardView inflate exceptions and a runtime crash. Adding google-guava didnt help.

I read the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/download) and downloaded this [library](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java/blob/master/CardboardSample/libs/libprotobuf-java-2.3-nano.jar)

Answer (score 1):

This alternative worked for me: https://github.com/raasun/treasurehunt

It's pretty much the same as the Cardboard sample project from Google except that it's compiled with Eclipse/ANT instead of Android Studio/gradle.

Just follow the first part of moyheen's instructions to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work on Eclipse, I just placed the Cardboard API jar ([cardboard.jar](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard/blob/master/CardboardSample/libs/cardboard.jar)) at the root folder of my app (alongside AndroidManifest.xml), and then in Build Path dialog I just did "Add Jar" and selected cardboard.jar.

Warning: Placing cardboard.jar in libs/ folder won't work, I tried, and it will produce an invalid APK that can't be installed.